# Run jenkins job based on previous job status

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-cli

I have scenario  where i need job to run only if the previous build was success .

if previous build had failed i need user to wait for admin apporval.

if previous build had success user can run the job.

can anyone help me how to go about it .

Answer (score 0):

Below is the pipeline script which will check the previous build and ask for the approval if the pervious build is failed or sucess

```
 pipeline{
agent any
stages{    
    stage('Previous Status check'){
        steps{
        echo "Checking"
        sleep 10
     } 
    }

stage('Deploy approval'){
    when {
                expression {
                    // When last build has failed
                    !hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS.equals(currentBuild.rawBuild.getPreviousBuild()?.getResult()) == true
                }
            }

    steps {
                input(message: 'last build was failed please check target group and approve', ok: 'Release!' , submitter: "ritesh.mahajan")
            }

}


stage('Building code on server'){
        steps{

          script {  
            def inputConfig
                    def inputTest

                    // Get the input
                    def userInput = input(
                            id: 'userInput', message: 'Enter the branch to build',
                            parameters: [

                                    string(defaultValue: 'Master',
                                            description: 'Enter the branch',
                                            name: 'Branch'),
                            ])

        inputbranch=userInput
        echo "${inputbranch}"
        echo "here we can execute script in remote machine by default it will build master ..we can also accept parameter"

          }

     } 
    }

}

}
```